# Unity - Assigning onclick to the instantiated prefab child and referencing cloned prefab's elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, assign

I have a prefab login panel, which is cloned with the following code:

```
public class LoginOpener : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject popupPrefab;

        protected Canvas m_canvas;
        protected GameObject m_popup;

        protected void Start()
        {
            m_canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas").GetComponent<Canvas>();
        }

        public virtual void OpenPopup()
        {
            m_popup = Instantiate(popupPrefab, m_canvas.transform, false);
            m_popup.SetActive(true);
            m_popup.transform.localScale = Vector3.zero;
            m_popup.GetComponent<Popup>().Open();
        }
    }
```

The prefab login panel has the following structure:

1. Login Panel

- Email Text
- Password Text
- Login Button
- Another button

And finally in the manager script I have the following:

```
public class FirebaseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Login References")]
    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_InputField loginEmail;
    [SerializeField]
    private TMP_InputField loginPassword;
    [SerializeField]
    public static FirebaseManager instance;

    public void LoginButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoginLogic(loginEmail.text, loginPassword.text));
    }
}
```

I need to assign the `public void LoginButton()` to the cloned prefab's login button as well as assigning cloned prefab's email and password texts to the manager's references.

As a newbie I failed to achieve this after two days of work. I tried onClick AddListener to the child element after cloning, or by finding the button with FindGameObjectWithTag, adding the reference script to the prefab.

I would really appreciate if you help me in this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't forget you are coding in Unity which like Unreal Engine is for making _games_ where performance is paramount; the last thing you want to do is follow _white-collar_ DI patterns  where people spend more time worrying about dependency injection and writing unit tests than working on the problem at hand.  Both of these technologies use excessive reflection and/or dynamic proxies both of which will hurt.   Check out [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/design-patterns-singleton-and-dependency-injection.547033/) thread over at the Unity forums.  The comments by **ippdev** are _gold!_

Comment: I'm sorry @MickyD, but saying that DI uses "excessive reflection and/or dynamic proxies" is incorrect. You would be correct in saying that *DI Containers* use excessive reflection (although most do so only at application startup), but DI by itself is a set of patterns and practices that don't require the use of a DI Container and can be applied without using any reflection whatsoever. Applying DI without a DI Container is called [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) which is a method I actually use for the applications I help build.

Comment: @Steven incorrect.   Unicorns have no place in gaming.

Comment: I'm sorry @MickyD, but can you point me out which parts of my comments are actually incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution working. I am sure there are more effective ways, but this solves the issue for now.

The following script is added to the login button of the prefab and the button is referenced via inspector. With this, the reference to a script does not disapper due to being a prefab.

```
public class logClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button CustomButton;
    private FirebaseManager _FirebaseManager;
    
    void Awake()
    {
        CustomButton.onClick.AddListener(CustomButton_onClick);
    }

    void CustomButton_onClick()
    {
        _FirebaseManager = FindObjectOfType<FirebaseManager>();
        _FirebaseManager.LoginButton();
    }
}
```

The following codes are added to the prefab instantiator. It adds tags to the input fields after instantiating.

```
m_popup = Instantiate(popupPrefab, m_canvas.transform, false);
GameObject ChildGameObject1 = m_popup.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(1).gameObject;
GameObject ChildGameObject2 = m_popup.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(2).gameObject;
ChildGameObject1.tag="loginmailtag";
ChildGameObject2.tag="loginpasstag";
```

Finally on our main script, we find the inputfield tags when we hit the login button. And then you can take their text values etc.

```
public void LoginButton()
    {
TMP_InputField loginmail = GameObject.FindWithTag("loginmailtag").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
TMP_InputField loginpass = GameObject.FindWithTag("loginpasstag").GetComponent<TMP_InputField>();
}
```